# Control in wpf and in mvvm pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

How can I design a control in wpf in such a way that while clicking on update button the focus should be on the particular row and the corresponding label should be displayed.
Please find the attached screen shot!

[image]

```
DataGrid x:Name="dataEmployee" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="76,71,0,0" IsReadOnly="True" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="121" Width="305" AutoGenerateColumns="False"> 
    <DataGrid.Columns> 
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Employee Id" Binding="{Binding EmployeeId}"/> 
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Employee Name" Binding="{Binding EmployeeName}"/> 
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Salary" Binding="{Binding EmployeeSalary}"/> 
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Designation" Binding="{Binding EmployeeDesignation}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Something with a `ListView` or a `DataGrid` will fit. You can have a `SelectedItem`/`SelectedIndex` in both. If you want more details, you will have to share what you tried.

Comment: Hi  P.Manthe , Thanks for answering I have tried with the data grid but the result set is binded to the grid as well.

Comment: this should work: `dataEmployee.SelectedIndex = 5;`. Of course if you have other part of the code that interact with the `Grid` that may not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could bind directly to the `DataGrid`:

```
<StackPanel>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataEmployee"  IsReadOnly="True" VerticalAlignment="Top" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Employee Id" Binding="{Binding EmployeeId}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Employee Name" Binding="{Binding EmployeeName}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Salary" Binding="{Binding EmployeeSalary}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Designation" Binding="{Binding EmployeeDesignation}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="Name"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=dataEmployee, Path=SelectedItem.EmployeeName}"/></StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

But since the specification says you should push on a button, let's do that also:

the XAML is almost the same:

```
<StackPanel>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataEmployee"  IsReadOnly="True" VerticalAlignment="Top" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Employee Id" Binding="{Binding EmployeeId}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Employee Name" Binding="{Binding EmployeeName}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Salary" Binding="{Binding EmployeeSalary}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Designation" Binding="{Binding EmployeeDesignation}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="Name"/>
        <TextBox Name="currentEmployeeName"/></StackPanel>
    <Button Height="30" Content="Update" Click="Button_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

And I created a simple `Class` to handle to data:

```
public class Employee
{

    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeSalary { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeDesignation { get; set; }
}
```

The remaining part is not difficult but must vary according to your DataModel of course. the important point is the `Button_Click` event:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<Employee> listEmployees = new List<Employee>();

        listEmployees.Add(new Employee() { EmployeeName = "Bob" });
        listEmployees.Add(new Employee() { EmployeeName = "Mary" });
        listEmployees.Add(new Employee() { EmployeeName = "Kato" });
        listEmployees.Add(new Employee() { EmployeeName = "Mohammed" });

        dataEmployee.ItemsSource = listEmployees;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Employee currentEmployee = dataEmployee.SelectedItem as Employee;

        if (currentEmployee == null)
        {
            currentEmployeeName.Text = "no selection";
        }
        else
        {
            currentEmployeeName.Text = currentEmployee.EmployeeName;
        }
     }
}
```